# How to extract numbers from strings separated by space and comma and receive list of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Suppose I have a string:

`hello 3.0 4.2, 2.5 6.0 8.0`

(all numbers positive) I would like to obtain a list of lists:

```
[[3.0,4.2],[2.5, 6.0, 8.0]]
```

(each number in float type) Is there any simple approach to do it, e.g., regex?

Comment: You will need 2 split operations

Comment: Is your desired result a list of lists of strings, or of numbers? Can the numbers be negative?

Comment: of float. Using split operation, I can manage it. In the present scope, all positive numbers.

Comment: P.S. I made a typo before in a comment I deleted, ```like confusing``` should be ```less confusing```. I am very sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) function

```python
import re
s = "input 3.0 4.2, 2.5 6.0 8.0"
for a in s.split(','):
 re.findall(r"[\d]+.[\d]+",a)
 
['3.0', '4.2']
['2.5', '6.0', '8.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```py
s = '3.0 4.2, 2.5 6.0 8.0'

l = [x.split(' ') for x in s.split(', ')]

print(l)
# [[3.0,4.2],[2.5, 6.0, 8.0]]
```